# How is Jasny Bootstrap's image upload -- instant preview implemented?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jasny-bootstrap

Does jasny upload the image onto my server? Or is it a local file?
If it is a local file, does it mean that our browser can access our private files?

Answer (score 0):

The preview is generated client side using a [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader) object.

```
reader.readAsDataURL(file)
```

You can take a look at the source code of the [`Fileinput.change` function](https://github.com/jasny/bootstrap/blob/master/js/fileinput.js#L63).